# 6 identical green balls are arranged in a line. how many different ways are there of arranging them?

Tags: combinatorics

> Six identical green balls are arranged in a line. How many different ways are there of arranging them?

I am not sure whether it is $1$ or $6! = 720$ (since they are identical). Also, part b asks the following:

> Four identical red balls and two identical yellow balls are arranged in a line. How many different ways are there of arranging them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is only one way of arranging 6 identical green balls in a line. No matter how you permute them, the configuration will be the same since all the balls are identical.

For 4 red and 2 yellow balls, the number of permutations are $$\frac{6!}{4!2!} = 15$$